# Pegando valor criado em tempo de execução

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando buscar um valor contido em uma tag (**span**) localizada em outro domínio utilizando PHP e JavaScript. Há casos em que eu consigo pegar o valor requerido mas na maioria o valor retornado é *null*. Acredito que quando dou um `file_get_contents` para buscar a span, e esta não aparece, é porque a mesma necessita dos scripts referentes a monta do valor.
Alguém já passou por uma situação semelhante e conseguiu resolver o problema?

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
        $regex = '/\<span class="special-price-value"(.*?)?\>(.|\\n)*?\<\/span\>/i';
        $url = file_get_contents("http://link.com.br");                                                         
        preg_match_all($regex, $url, $scripts);
        print_r($scripts);
```

Comment: Está buscando com o PHP de que forma? está usando DomDocument ou apenas o File_get_contents?

Comment: apenas file_get_content, passando o link de onde quero buscar

Comment: Poderia colocar a parte do seu código que está em dúvida? Assim facilitaria ajudar você.

Comment: Adicionei o bloco em meu post!

Comment: ah, você está tentando pegar pelo PHP!

Comment: Sim, agora, mas já havia tentado por JavaScript também haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não consegui pegar o valor com o DOMdocument pois o mesmo não carrega valores mandados para as tags via JavaScript. 
Minha solução foi usar o próprio JavaScript para buscar os valores requeridos.

Answer (score 3):

Para que complicar utilizando Regex para fazer parse de HTML? Use [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php) e *Xpath*:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://link.com.br"));
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$spans = $xml->xpath('//span[@class="special-price-value"]');

foreach ($spans as $span)
{
    echo $span->nodeValue;;
}
```

Comment: +1. Já estava preparando essa resposta no meu `localhost/teste/index.php`. Pelo menos, relembrei como usa!

Comment: Mas no meu caso, o site referente a busca do valor pode conter, por exemplo um &. Isso ocasionaria em um erro de parse, não?

Comment: Algo assim ? `http://link.com.br?teste=foo&bar=teste`

Comment: Também, mas se neste caso eu conseguiria dar um escape. Mas e quando os caracteres estão dentro do site? O file_get_contents ira me retornar o HTML e o loadHTML carregara o mesmo, portanto, quando o loadHTML chegasse nesse caractere, o erro apareceria. Se tivesse como, daria até para executar um str_replace, mas como o link que varrerei pode alternar e não esta no mesmo domínio, não conseguiria fazer isso.

Comment: @HenriqueCosta não entendi qual sua preocupação... por que o `&` causaria algum erro ? Se possível abra uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe, acho que o str_replace funcionará sim, pois eu terei o html carregado em minha variável...

Comment: Pelo que entendi isso já é uma outra dúvida. Caso a resposta tenha resolvido seu problema inicial, aceite a resposta e faça outra pergunta se necessário. Leia mais em [tour]

Comment: @gmsantos O & fara com que o parse pense que temos uma entity reference (e.g. ©). Em alguns casos, isso retorna ; e então é declarado que o documento acabou.

Answer (score 1):

Henrique ao invés de utilizar expressões regulares você poderia utilizar os recursos desta biblioteca [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), com ela é muito simples varrer o html veja um exemplo do proprio manual:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');//seu site aqui

// Find all spans 
foreach($html->find('span') as $element) 
   echo $element . '<br>';
//$html->find('span[id=especial]')
```

Comment: você pode utilizar todos os tipos de seletores(iguais aos do CSS) necessarios para encontrar os elementos desejados

Comment: Acho que um exemplo usando a estrutura que ele quer utilizar seja mais útil.

Comment: No meu exemplo será encontrado e impresso toda span encontrada no link disposto em file_get_html, para obter um resultado mais filtrado poderá adicionar um seletor especifico como id,class,name

Comment: Já havia tentado dessa forma, com o file_get_html. Consegui localizar a tag que queria, mas entre ela, o valor estava em nulo

Comment: Algumas spans podem ter seu valores carregados coma Ajax?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Por isso quando tento carrega-las o valor retorna null.